# Kernel version by uniq hostname

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a input file with the following example data.

kernel_version hostname

```
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 www01.dc1.domain.com
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 www02.dc1.domain.com
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 exc01.dc1.domain.com
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 exc02.dc1.domain.com
2.6.32-120.el6.x86_64 www03.dc2.domain.com
2.6.32-120.el6.x86_64 www04.dc2.domain.com
2.6.32-120.el6.x86_64 exc03.dc2.domain.com
2.6.32-120.el6.x86_64 exc04.dc2.domain.com
2.6.32-100.el6.x86_64 www05.dc3.domain.com
2.6.32-100.el6.x86_64 www06.dc3.domain.com
2.6.32-100.el6.x86_64 exc05.dc3.domain.com
2.6.32-100.el6.x86_64 exc06.dc3.domain.com
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 www07.dc4.domain.com
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 www08.dc4.domain.com
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 exc07.dc4.domain.com
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 exc08.dc4.domain.com
```

I'd like to output the unique kernel version, and which dcs are running which.

For example;

```
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 dc1, dc4
2.6.32-120.el6.x86_64 dc2
2.6.32-100.el6.x86_64 dc3
```

What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Heading should rather read, kernel version by unique dc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %kernels;
open INPUT,"<inputfile";

while (<INPUT>)
{
    my ($version, $hostname) = split(/\s+/,$_);
    if ($kernels{$version}) { $kernels{$version} .= ", $hostname" }
    else { $kernels{$version} = $hostname }
}
close INPUT;    

# Print the summary
foreach my $kernel (keys(%kernels)) {   print "$kernel\t$kernels{$kernel}\n"; }
```

<strike>**Warning:** I did not test this script. I am not responsible for any syntax errors, race conditions, or velociraptor attacks that may be caused by this code.. but it should get you started</strike>

**Edit:** I have now tested it. One syntactical error that has been rectified, and no major velociraptor attacks.

Comment: Does as it says on the tin. Thanks!

Comment: from commandline: `perl -ne <inputfile '$str{$1}->{$2}++ if /(\S+)\s[^.]+\.([^.]+)\./;END { map { printf "%s %s\n", $_, join(", ",keys %{$str{$_}}); } keys %str;}'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/ [^\.]*\.\([^.]*\).*/ \1/' file |
sort -u |
sed ':a;$!N;s/^\(\(.*\) .*\)\n.*\2/\1,/;ta;P;D'
```

This gives the  result but not in original order, for original order use:

```
sed 's/ [^\.]*\.\([^.]*\).*/ \1/' file |
cat -n - |
sort -uk2,3 |
sed ':a;$!N;s/^\(.\{7\}\(.*\) .*\)\n.*\2/\1,/;ta;P;D' |
sort -n | 
sed 's/^.\{7\}//'
```

Comment: Well and nice! (the condition `$!` seem not to be necessary, as `P;D` as sed will anyway print each lines: the second sed could be simplier: `:a;N;s/^\(.*\) \(.*\)\n\1 /\1 \2, /;ta` )

Comment: @F.Hauri the `P;D` is necessary when 2 or more `dc`'s are collected because the `N` appends the next record and this might then have a `dc` collected to it etc. `$!N` although not necessary with all seds is logically correct and is a catch-all condition.